# the best componenents to use in UI?

Tags: android, widget

i'm working on an app that records audio. the sample is saved on the sd card. At the moment my UI just has the buttons to record,play and reverse the sample. what i'd like is a way to specify a file name for the sample and a menu to play previously recorded samples. could someone tell me which widgets would be best for this. i'm thinking textbox/keyboard, context menu or some sort of list. not sure of the terminology.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would really recommend this:

[Google IO 2010 - Design Patterns - Video](http://www.google.com/events/io/2010/sessions/android-ui-design-patterns.html)
If you don't have that much time just check the slides:

[Google IO 2010 - Design Patterns - Slides](http://dl.google.com/googleio/2010/android-android-ui-design-patterns.pdf)
Video is much more comprehensive though!!! Good luck!

Me and others already answered some sort of a similar question here:

[Prettifying my Android App?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4880748/prettifying-my-android-app/4881486#4881486)

Comment: You should definitely check out this years version of the session, too - http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WGIU2JX1U5Y

Answer (score 1):

Buttons are the best components to use. Who'd disagree on that? :) You ask us to design a UI layout for you? Be more specific. Check out the available UI widgets and design something nice. It's your app.

Comment: this should be a comment on the question rather then answer

Comment: @Javanator :) no i'm not asking you to design it, merely give me some guidence on the terminology for the widgets. i'm new to android and have only done web app programming before and not sure which compnents give the desired effct:) thanks anyway